# URL title field is blank on some entries! Help

Tags: safecracker, channel-form, url-title

I have a channel for users to add their own entry via a Safecracker form, it is a live site and there is now 800 odd entries – about 300 of these have slipped by without URL titles, which you can imagine is causing trouble...

**Blank URL title:**

In some instance, it seems that my URL titles have not came through – they are blank. Would this signal a lack on Javascript in the users browser? URL title field is hidden. It all works fine when I test it with Javascript enabled, could only recreate the problem with JS disabled, no URL title comes into the fields value.

My question on this is – how do I prevent this from happening within Safecracker? These users would not understand url title field, so want to keep it hidden – which means can't user validate it.

**Rebuilding the URLS using title**

I have seen a few solutions on here – but none work. SQL solution leaves in special characters. PHP solution throws up an error.

If I need to rebuild all the URL titles in a Channel, how do I go about it? (I am not good with PHP or MySQL – is there an existing solution I am missing)

I am stuck with about 300 blank URLs, which would be tedious to do manually.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to test this, but [MX Title Control](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-title-control) allows you to update all entries with a pattern. You could set the URL Title Pattern to `{title}` and try updating that way. As always, backup first before giving it a shot